# Creating new dictionary from existing dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a new dictionary (new_dict), from the old dictionary(my_dict), in new_dict values of the my_dict will be keys and keys will be values.

Expected output:

```
{"name" : [1, 3, 5], "last_name": [2, 4, 6]}
```

But, I am getting:

```
{"name" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], "last_name": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}
```

This is my code:

```
def my_function(my_dict):
    # Creating new dictionary
    new_dict = dict.fromkeys(set(my_dict.values()), [])

    for key, value in my_dict.items():
        new_dict[value].append(key)

    return new_dict

# Existing dictionary
my_dict = {
    1: "name",
    2: "last_name",
    3: "name",
    4: "last_name",
    5: "name",
    6: "last_name"}
res = my_function(my_dict)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line:

```
new_dict.fromkeys(set(my_dict.values()), [])
```

creates a dictionary with the very same list as a value for each key, so later you append to the same list, too.

You can use dict comprehension in this case:

```
new_dict = { k: [] for k in my_dict.values() }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `collections.defaultdict(list)` to create a dictionary of `list` values:

```py
import collections

my_dict = {
    1: "name",
    2: "last_name",
    3: "name",
    4: "last_name",
    5: "name",
    6: "last_name",
}

d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for num, text in my_dict.items():
    d[text].append(num)
```

You get what you want.

See the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Quoting an [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples):

```py
>>> s = [('yellow', 1), ('blue', 2), ('yellow', 3), ('blue', 4), ('red', 1)]
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k, v in s:
...     d[k].append(v)
...
>>> sorted(d.items())
[('blue', [2, 4]), ('red', [1]), ('yellow', [1, 3])]
```

Comment: The OP wanted a function.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you can do:

```
my_dict = {1: "name",
           2: "last_name",
           3: "name",
           4: "last_name",
           5: "name",
           6: "last_name"}

def my_function(my_dict):

    new_dict = {v:[k for k in my_dict.keys() if my_dict[k] == v] for v in my_dict.values()}

    return new_dict

print(my_function(my_dict))
```

Output:

```
{'name': [1, 3, 5], 'last_name': [2, 4, 6]}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the whole data is in this format, Your can use the odd/even property of the keys:

```
def func(my_dict):
    new_dict = {}
    new_dict['name'] = {}
    new_dict['last_name'] = {}
    for i in my_dict.keys():
        if i%2 == 1 :
            new_dict['name'].append(i)
        else :
            new_dict['last_name'].append(i)
    return new_dict
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but, there is no such constraint that dictionary values will be in an odd/ even manner.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `collections.defaultdict`, or use `dict.setdefault`. There is already an answer using `defaultdict`, so I show the second option:

```
new_dict = {}
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    vv = new_dict.setdefault(v, [])
    vv.append(k)
```

Comment: The OP wanted a function.

Comment: I hope they are able to write a function based on this code... Oh I see, you are just trolling every answer.

Answer (score -1):

Apologize for my previous ans. Here is the updated one. It can achieve the result though it needs improvement. Share your thoughts for optimization, please :)

```
new_dict = {v: [x for x, y in my_dict.items() if y == v] for k, v in my_dict.items() }
```

{'name': [1, 3, 5], 'last_name': [2, 4, 6]}

Comment: This does not work because it is necessary to match multiple `k` values to the same `v` key, and accumulate them in a list.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel please check now